# How can I return a wchar_t** - null terminated array of UNICODE strings - to a Python script using CTypes

Tags: c++, c, python-3.x, ctypes

Given two functions implemented in a shared library called `c-lib.so`, how can I correctly define/wrap the functions using CTypes.

```c
set_list_of_strings(wchar_t** list);

wchar_t** get_list_of_strings();
```

For the set function, the following works if added to a python wrapper module

```
import ctypes

_lib = ctypes.CDLL('c-lib.so')

def set_list_of_strings(list):
    global _dsl
    arr = (ctypes.c_wchar_p * len(list))
    arr[:] = list
    _lib.set_list_of_strings(arr)
```

I have two questions related to the above.

1. How would I define the `set_list_of_strings.argtypes[??] to check/restrict the input.
2. How would I define the wrapper function to correctly return the list of strings.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a simple example where the C (in fact wrapped C++) code gets a list of strings and copy them then the `get_list_of_strings` function returns them suffixed with the string position.

As for the definition of the function in python:

```py
    # wchar_t** get_list_of_strings()
    get_list_of_strings.restype = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_wchar_p)

    # void set_list_of_strings(wchar_t** list)
    set_list_of_strings.argtypes = (ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_wchar_p), )
```

The way to get the string out of the `wchar_t**` is quite simple: you can index the returned pointer itself and get the strings out of it. Since the returned array end with the `nullptr` (converted to `None`) you can just stop the iteration at that point:

```py
    result = get_list_of_strings()
    index = 0
    while True:
        p = result[index]
        if p is None:
            break
        index += 1
        print(p)
```

The tricky part is initializing the array of `wchar_t*` pointer:

```py
def list_to_wchar_t_pp(l):
    if not l:
        return None
    buffers = [ctypes.create_unicode_buffer(s) for s in l]
    addresses = list(map(ctypes.addressof, buffers))
    addresses.append(0) # append nullptr at the end
    pp = (ctypes.c_wchar_p * (len(l) + 1))(*addresses)
    return pp
```

We create Unicode buffers from the strings, get the addresses of those buffers, add a null pointer at the end. Then we initialize the array of pointers with those addresses.

Python Code:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
import string
import ctypes

def list_to_wchar_t_pp(l):
    if not l:
        return None
    buffers = [ctypes.create_unicode_buffer(s) for s in l]
    addresses = list(map(ctypes.addressof, buffers))
    addresses.append(0) # append nullptr at the end
    pp = (ctypes.c_wchar_p * (len(l) + 1))(*addresses)
    return pp


def main():
    dll = ctypes.WinDLL(r"TestDll.dll")

    # wchar_t** get_list_of_strings()
    get_list_of_strings = dll.get_list_of_strings
    get_list_of_strings.restype = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_wchar_p)

    # void set_list_of_strings(wchar_t** list)
    set_list_of_strings = dll.set_list_of_strings
    set_list_of_strings.argtypes = (ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_wchar_p), )

    strings = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
    pp_strings = list_to_wchar_t_pp(strings)
    if not pp_strings:
        return -1

    set_list_of_strings(pp_strings)

    result = get_list_of_strings()
    index = 0
    while True:
        p = result[index]
        if p is None:
            break
        index += 1
        print(p)

    return 0



if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

---

Output:

```
foo #1
bar #2
baz #3
```

---

C++ code for the shared lib (Windows DLL); note that freeing the global buffer and its pointers should be implemented as well.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

#define EXTERN_DLL_EXPORT extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)

static wchar_t** g_list;

EXTERN_DLL_EXPORT void set_list_of_strings(wchar_t** list)
{
    auto count = 0;
    while(true)
    {
        const auto p = list[count];
        if (p == nullptr)
            break;
        count++;
    }

    if (count == 0)
        return;

    g_list = new wchar_t* [count + 1];
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        const auto s = list[i];
        const auto len = wcslen(s);
        auto p = new wchar_t[len + 1];
        wcscpy_s(p, len + 1, s);
        g_list[i] = p;
    }

    g_list[count] = nullptr;
}

EXTERN_DLL_EXPORT wchar_t** get_list_of_strings()
{
    if (g_list == nullptr)
        return nullptr;

    auto count = 0;
    while(true)  {
        const auto p = g_list[count];
        if (p == nullptr)
            break;
        count++;
    }

    if (count == 0)
        return nullptr;

    const auto new_list = new wchar_t* [count + 1];
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        std::wstring ws(g_list[i]);
        ws += L" #" + std::to_wstring(i + 1);
        const auto length = ws.length();

        const auto buff_len = ws.length() + 1; 
        const auto buff = new wchar_t[buff_len];

        wcscpy_s(buff, ws.length() + 1, ws.data());

        new_list[i] = buff;
    }

    new_list[count] = nullptr;

    return new_list;
}
```

Comment: Forgive me if I'm breaking the comment rules here, but I need to thank you!! for such a complete and detailed working example.